# Android I don't understand nine patch tool

Tags: android

Android I don't understand nine patch tool and why we use the nine patch and what is the benefits of using nine patch .I think it is used for small images in order to not loose quality when it is scaled.
plz can anyone give me detail explanation about why we use nine patch ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a tutorial site.

Comment: Literally the first link I found when I googled _why do we need 9-patch_. At least try to put in some effort, OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since android has a lot of different screensizes, it feels natural to have the images being able to scale properly, without losing its original look, and that's where Nine Patch comes in.

Nine Patch will make the images scale, by breaking it up, like if you think that the X's are the part of the image that you want static, but want to scale the part of the image around it.

| | | **XXXX** | | |

Then it's possible with Nine Patch to scale/drag the areas around the part you want to be static, like this:

| | | | | | | **XXXX** | | | | | | |

Without losing any 'originality' to the part of the image that you didn't want to scale. You more or less make the areas around the static part dynamic, so they can change, both in width and height.